# Why is running a MANOVA insignificant with multiple predictors but significant with just one at a time and which should I rely on?

Tags: r, manova

When running a MANOVA with multiple predictor variables, I get insignificant results. When running it with a single one of my predictors at a time its significant. Why and which should I rely on?

```
model <- lm(cbind(DV1, DV2, DV3, DV4, DV5,... DV20) ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV3 + IV4 + IV5, data = MYDATA)
Manova(model)
```

insignificant p-values

```
model.1 <- lm(cbind(DV1, DV2, DV3, DV4, DV5,... DV20) ~ IV1, data = MYDATA)
Manova(model.1)

model.2 <- lm(cbind(DV1, DV2, DV3, DV4, DV5,... DV20) ~ IV2, data = MYDATA)
Manova(model.2)
```

significant p-values

Any explanation on why these return different results and which would be more appropriate would be much appreciated.

Comment: My guess would be correlation between your predictors.  Even if you shared your data, we couldn't tell you which to rely on.  That decision requires thought, insight and understanding of your dataset, how it was collected and what the objectives of your experiment are.  Only you and your colleagues can know those last. One thing to bear in mind: the world is not a dichotomy between "significant" and "(sic) insignificant".

Comment: Flagging this question to move it into Cross Validated where stats discussions are more appropriate